# Terrible HORROR MS Excel + MS query! Can't assign an "AS" to a field

Tags: excel

### I'm freaking!

I have this query:

```
 SELECT 
 l.GRUPO as group
 FROM STKQRY.LISTA_ARTIGOS9_F1 l
```

and it works!

but this fails:

```
 SELECT 
 l.GRUPO as group2
 FROM STKQRY.LISTA_ARTIGOS9_F1 l
```

even this:

```
 SELECT 
 l.GRUPO as a
 FROM STKQRY.LISTA_ARTIGOS9_F1 l
```

even this:

```
 SELECT 
 l.GRUPO as a09a8sdahjasda098dasdhjasdhouasd9
 FROM STKQRY.LISTA_ARTIGOS9_F1 l
```

even this:

```
 SELECT 
 l.GRUPO as groupadasdasfagsdgsag
 FROM STKQRY.LISTA_ARTIGOS9_F1 l
```

Error:

> The item at groupadasdasfagsdgsag is not valid. Valid testimunes

If I do:

```
 SELECT 
 l.GRUPO as groupadasdasfagsdgsag
 FROM STKQRY.LISTA_ARTIGOS9_F1 as l
```

(notice the as after "LISTA_ARTIGOS9_F1")
then the fields are as original, in this case "grupo", instead of "groupadasdasfagsdgsag" as expected!
but excel team like to give us more work..

How the ****?

thanks for your help...

if I change other field to other names it works with no problem!

I've restarted the PC, tried with another excel file, but no luck!

Comment: SOLVED! in this case, but only for the field l.grupo I MUST do like this: STKQRY.LISTA_ARTIGOS9_F1 as l. I must put that "AS" before "l". Crazy, bacause with other fields I don't have to.. wtf excel!

Comment: need more information: how does your database look like?

Comment: Well not exactly, now the fields have their original names! wtf

Comment: the problem is with excel 100% sure becuse I don't have another field named "groupadasdasfagsdgsag" in my table...

Comment: dont get the problem. you're getting the error BECAUSE the field dosnt exist and you try to convert data to its type. so whats the problem?

Comment: the field "grupo" exists because if I do "grupo as group" it works. But If I do "grupo as groupadasdasfagsdgsag" desn't work. This is only to change the field name

Answer (score 0):

did you try using double quotes?

```
SELECT 
l.GRUPO "group2"
FROM STKQRY.LISTA_ARTIGOS9_F1 l
```

or

```
SELECT 
l.GRUPO AS "group2"
FROM STKQRY.LISTA_ARTIGOS9_F1 l
```